# Which bot framework to use (if any) for a Kik, Facebook, & Slack messaging bot using javascript?

Tags: botframework, slack, chatbot, kik, facebook-chatbot

I'm building a chatbot that will need to be launched on Kik, Facebook, and Slack. I'm unsure of where to start in terms of using a bot framework or whether I should create something custom myself.

I don't believe I will need any NLP. The user is going to be pushed down a very structured path, that will use buttons to guide the users to the next prompts and will also share with the user links and media.

Microsoft Bot Framework seems like the main framework I should look at, but its unclear to me how useful it will be if I end up wanting to deliver responses that are custom to each messaging platform. Meaning, on Facebook I may want to take advantage of a custom feature that they have like buttons or templates and on Kik I will want to take advantage of suggested keyboards.

Any suggestions or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Questions asking users to recommend a resource are off-topic for Stack overflow, you may find one of the sister sites a better places to post this.

Comment: Which sister site would you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

BotFramework will do the translation for you.  Write to the BotFramework schema and it will using buttons for Facebook and keyboards for Kik.